# What is SSG (Nuxt.js, Gatsby) doing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nuxt.js, gatsby, ssg

I have heard SSG generates static sites.
Then I thought SSG generates pure HTML that didn't include React, but I think it may not be true now.

I think:

1. SSG generates a usual React App and rendered HTMLs for initialization.
   As it is a usual React App, if I click a button and trigger a side effect, client-side rendering will be triggered and the page will be updated.
2. When routing using router is triggered, next page's js file and data obtained when build will be downloaded, and then client-side rendering will be triggered.
   The next page's rendered HTML for initialization isn't used here.

Is it true?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I think your answer was little bit off my intention. So I can't select your answer to best answer, but I appliciate you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSG (**S**tatic **S**ite **G**enerators) like Gatsby and Next, what they do is to create an output HTML based on a React environment code. This doesn't mean that the site is "static" in terms of interaction. This means that the page you are requesting is already created so you are avoiding response and compilation time in the server.

Summarizing, given a "traditional"/"old-fashioned" PHP site. When you request the homepage, for example, your requests go to the server, the server transpiles the PHP into HTML (what the browser can parse and print) and then you get the page. That processing time is omitted in Gatsby/Next because the HTML is already created.

When you build your site in Gatsby/Next, the data is being retrieved from the sources (using GraphQL from markdowns, CMSs, APIs, JSONs, etc) and creates the output (that's why there's a `/public` folder generated). All your JavaScript and React is bundled into the output HTML so your website will be "dynamic" in terms of user interactivity, React is part of the ecosystem so your side-effects (triggered by `useEffect` hook for example) or your [rehydration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/react-hydration/) process (`useState` hook for example) will be part of your site.

Explained as:

[image: Gatsby scheme]

When you navigate into another page, you are requesting a page that is already built and generated, that's why is so blazingly fast.

Answer (score 2):

I've answered this question few weeks ago on the Nuxt discussions: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/discussions/9493#discussioncomment-948643

Let's say that SSG bring several things:

- SEO
- speed
- ecology
- [probably some other things]

There are several ways of doing SSG and all of them have their pro/cons and their use-cases. For the most part, and if you're using [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/), you will probably go the `target: static`, `ssr: true` route.

This will:

- generate fully static pages during build time and you'll be able to host it on Netlify, Vercel or alike
- hydrate the static content with some JS after you have fetched the static files
- have the Vue behavior afterwards, as a classic SPA (hence managing the routing without further server calls)

This behavior is called Isomorphic or Universal, more info in the linked discussion.

---

Gatsby and Next.js do work in somewhat similar ways. There are some minor differences but the general is globally the same across those 3 AFAIK.

[SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) and [Astro](https://astro.build/) handle this a bit differently. May be interesting to give it a look!